# NHibernate is unable to save the record - PK Id violation

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I ran out of any ideas of why such a simple thing as saving a new record is causing NHibernate to fail.

So I have an class:

```
public class TimeSlot
{
    public virtual int TimeSlotId { get; set; }
    public virtual int TimeProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParkingDisabled { get; set; }
    public virtual int DayOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a mapping class:

```
public class TimeSlotMap : ClassMap<TimeSlot>
{
    public TimeSlotMap()
    {
        Table("TimeSlot");
        Id(x => x.TimeSlotId, "TimeSlotId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.TimeProfileId, "TimeProfileId");
        Map(x => x.StartTime, "StartTime").CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.EndTime, "EndTime").CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ParkingDisabled, "ParkingDisabled");
        Map(x => x.DayOfWeek, "DayOfWeek");
    }
}
```

When defining Id I tried with our without .GeneratedBy.Identity(), with or withouth .UnsavedValue(0) but nothing prevents NHibernate from throwing a following exception when trying to save a new TimeSlot instance. (Save, SaveOrUpdate, they both throw this exception).

When saving a new TimeSlot TimeSlotId is 0, remaining properties have valid values.

The exception is:
{"could not insert: [***.Entities.Models.ParkingRestriction][SQL: INSERT INTO TimeSlot (TimeProfileId, StartTime, EndTime, ParkingDisabled, DayOfWeek) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]"}

Inner exception which says a lot is:
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'TimeSlot_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TimeSlot'. The duplicate key value is (13).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Of course it has a record with TimeSlotId = 13, it was there in the DB even before the application was started. 
Somehow NHibernate it trying to 'guess' the next available Id but it does it incorrectly.

**QUESTION:**
Is it possible to force NHibernate to INSERT a new record without specifying the ID at all so that SQL assigns it itself? That should be the default behaviour.

Here you will find SQL definition of TimeSlot table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeSlot](
    [TimeSlotId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [TimeProfileId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DayOfWeek] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ParkingDisabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [TimeSlot_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TimeSlotId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimeSlot]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [TimeProfile_TimeSlot_FK1] FOREIGN KEY([TimeProfileId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TimeProfile] ([TimeProfileId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimeSlot] CHECK CONSTRAINT [TimeProfile_TimeSlot_FK1]
GO
```

Thanks, Radek

**UPDATE:**
I checked with the profiler. The SQL INSERT statement DOES NOT contain identity column. The following statement is executed:
"exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO TimeSlot (TimeProfileId, StartTime, EndTime, ParkingDisabled, DayOfWeek) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 int,@p1 datetime,@p2 datetime,@p3 int,@p4 int',@p0=2,@p1='1970-01-01 09:30:00',@p2='1970-01-01 18:30:00',@p3=0,@p4=6".
When executing from the application level it fails. When executed from SQL Management studio it succeeds.
It looks like possibly something is screwing the session state before this call. Just my guess.

Comment: if i'm not wrong, the Id comes from your db and you need to tell the identifier where it is. It seems that you have rows in the table but the identifier thinks that they are not there.

Comment: Alter the column `TimeSlotId` in your `TimeSlot` table to the maximum id of your existing rows. Something like `IDENTITY(14,1)`

Comment: I think it is obvious that NHibernate cannot assume that all tables are empty when starting the application. Or as Rabban suggested they have 13 rows. ;)

Comment: The Problem comes from your Table in the Database, not from NHibernate. Depending on the Dialect and IdGenerator you use, NHibernate ask the DB for the next row and creates an Insert statement with this Id, or it creates an insert statement without an Id and the Database returns the new created id.

Comment: I need to force NHibernate to use the second option you mentioned, that is an INSERT without an Id given. How do I achieve it?

Comment: It seems that i was not clear enough, sorry ;) It doesn't matter how NHibernate creates the Inserts, in both ways the Id comes from your DB, NOT from Nhibernate. you need to alter your Table in the DB like i suggested before and everything should work.

Comment: You need to exchange "14" with your highest id + 1. `alter table [dbo].[TimeSlot] alter column [TimeSlotId] [int] IDENTITY(14,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL`